# Microsoft.Whiteboard app taking up 10+GB

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-store

Here's what I see - tons of copies of this windows store app, and each one is a different version:

[image: Microsoft.Whiteboard]

The app is not even installed on the PC, I uninstalled it using powershell:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers -Name Microsoft.Whiteboard | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
```

The folders (and data) are still there, and I can't edit anything in the Appxvolume. I've tried these commands to try and find them, but no luck:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online
```

I ran `WSReset.exe`, but it didn't remove the files.

I don't need to keep any of the windows store data, but it does need to still work so I don't want to just rip out those files.

There are other apps that duplicated as well, and they all total about 11GB, this is running 1803, and I don't have enough space left to update it.

What is the best way to clean these out?

Comment: "What is the best way to clean these out?" - Take ownership of the individual folders then delete them, you should avoid modifying the permissions on the WindowsApps directory itself, that cause problems that are not easily solved.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I wasn't able to delete everything, but enough to get most of my space back.